# What are Javascript/AJAX times in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Are the times in milliseconds or seconds or what? I'm not sure why these two scripts don't happen at the same time - there's a sizable delay.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#idle").delay(300000).fadeIn(500);
});

var intervalHandler;
var counter = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        intervalHandler = setInterval(function() {
            $('#chatresults').load('includes/chat.php');
            counter++;
            if (counter == 200) {
                clearInterval(intervalHandler);
            }
        }, 1500); 
    });
```

The second script should run 200 times, each being 1500 in length (not sure of unit - probably milliseconds), which equals 300000 in total. For some reason, it doesn't end at the same time as the first one goes, there's a big delay between them. Is there any obvious reason why?

Comment: Yes, it is measured in milliseconds

Comment: Also, dont forget to clear counter to be 0 when you ClearInterval

Comment: More infos here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS timers aren't accurate when used like that because between each two iterations there is some time wasted on executing the actual code. So the more iterations there are, the more off will the time be.

One solution is to set a time when everything should finish and rely on that instead of going interval + code execution + interval + code execution, etc...

But in your case, this might be the best approach:

```
if (counter == 200) {
    clearInterval(intervalHandler);
    $("#idle").fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: I feel so dumb for not even thinking of that. Thank you.

Comment: @Shomz Can i ask you something ?

Comment: @Shomz Can you check my question ? [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176243/imagecreatefromgif-from-base64-encoded-animated-gif-in-post)

Comment: @Shomz If you agree to answer. I will give you all the details.